# How do I split a string that contains different signs?

Tags: javascript, string, replace, split, match

I want to split a string that can look like this:  word1;word2;word3,word4,word5,word6.word7. etc.

The string is from an output that I get from a php page that collects data from a database so the string may look different but the first words are always separated with ; and then , and the last words with .(dot)

I want to be able to fetch all the words that ends with for example ; , or . into an array. Does someone know how to do this?

I would also like to know how to fetch only the words that ends with ;

The function ends_with(string, character) below works but it takes no regard to whitespace. For example if the word is Jonas Sand, it only prints Sand. Anybody knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably

```
var string = "word1;word2;word3,word4,word5,word6.word7";
var array = string.split(/[;,.]/);
// array = ["word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5", "word6", "word7"]
```

The key is in the regular expression passed to the `String#split` method. The character class operator `[]` allows the regular expression to select between the characters contained with it.

If you need to split on a string that contains more than one character, you can use the `|` to differentiate.

```
var array = string.split(/;|,|./) // same as above
```

**Edit:** Didn't thoroughly read the question. Something like this

```
var string = "word1;word2;word3,word4,word5,word6.word7";

function ends_with(string, character) {
  var regexp = new RegExp('\\w+' + character, 'g');
  var matches = string.match(regexp);
  var replacer = new RegExp(character + '$');
  return matches.map(function(ee) {
    return ee.replace(replacer, '');
  });
}
// ends_with(string, ';') => ["word1", "word2"]
```

Comment: But if I just want the words that end with ;

Comment: Still get problems when for exampel word3 have whitespace like 
;James,Jonas Sand, the code only prints out Howard,Sand

Answer (score 0):

```
var myString = word1;word2;word3,word4,word5,word6.word7;
var result = myString.split(/;|,|./);
```