# How to Split string with multiple rules in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, split

I have this string for example:

```
str = "my name is john#doe oh.yeh";
```

the end result I am seeking is this Array:

```
strArr = ['my','name','is','john','&#doe','oh','&yeh'];
```

which means 2 rules apply:

1. split after each space " " (I know how)
2. **if there are special characters ("." or "#") then also split but add the characther "&" before the word with the special character.**

I know I can strArr = str.split(" ") for the first rule. but how do I do the other trick?

thanks,
Alon

Comment: Should it be `'&#doe'` or `'&doe'`? You have `'&yeh'` and not `'&.yeh'`.

Comment: Do you expect to have those "special characters" as part of the input or there's no way any of them will occur even once?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I split a string that contains different signs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880332/how-do-i-split-a-string-that-contains-different-signs)

Comment: @outis Did you miss the second part?

Comment: @RobW: no, but this is really two questions, the first of which has already been asked. Currently looking for another of the second.

Comment: ... [Finding a substring and inserting another string after it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5865257/), [string.split(regex) keep seperators](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4204210/), though the answer for the latter is more complex than necessary for this particular problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the result should be `'&doe'` and not `'&#doe'`, a simple solution would be to just replace all `.` and `#` with `&` split by spaces:

```
strArr = str.replace(/[.#]/g, ' &').split(/\s+/)
```

`/\s+/` matches consecutive white spaces instead of just one.

If the result should be `'&#doe'` and `'&.yeah'` use the same regex and add a capture:

```
strArr = str.replace(/([.#])/g, ' &$1').split(/\s+/)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a Regular expression, to match all special characters at once. By "special", I assume that you mean "no letters".

```
var pattern = /([^ a-z]?)[a-z]+/gi;             // Pattern
var str = "my name is john#doe oh.yeh";         // Input string
var strArr = [], match;                         // output array,  temporary var
while ((match = pattern.exec(str)) !== null) {  // <-- For each match
   strArr.push( (match[1]?'&':'') + match[0]);  // <-- Add to array
}
// strArr is now:
// strArr = ['my', 'name', 'is', 'john', '&#doe', 'oh', '&.yeh']
```

It does not match consecutive special characters. The pattern has to be modified for that. Eg, if you want to include all consecutive characters, use `([^ a-z]+?)`.

Also, it does nothing include a last special character. If you want to include this one as well, use `[a-z]*` and remove `!== null`.

Answer (score 0):

use split() method. That's what you need:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Ok. i saw, you found it, i think:

1) first use split to the whitespaces 
2) iterate through your array, split again in array members when you find # or . 
3) iterate through your array again and `str.replace("#", "&#")` and `str.replace(".","&.")` when you find

Answer (score 0):

I would think a combination of split() and replace() is what you are looking for:

```
str = "my name is john#doe oh.yeh";

strArr = str.replace('\W',' &');

strArr = strArr.split(' ');
```

That should be close to what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
array = string.replace(/#|\./g, ' &$&').split(' ');
```

Take a look at demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/M6fQ7/1/