# Trying to combine an exlude and include regex expression

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, match

After asking a question about it here: [How to Split string with multiple rules in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351907/how-to-split-string-with-multiple-rules-in-javascript#comment11807472_9351907)

I got stuck in another string issue

I have this regex:

```
Txt.replace(/([^ ][.#:])/g, ' &$1').split(" ");
```

I want the condition to be: if there is "." or "#" or ":" **but there is no whitespace before them** then apply the condition.

so for `foo#bar` I will get : `foo &#bar`  (in my array `['foo','&#bar']`)

but for `foo #bar` nothing will happen and it will stay the same (in my array `['foo','#bar']`)

**The problem is that when I write** `foo#bar` I get --> `"fo&o#bar"` **the letters mix and no splitting has happened - it is wrong**

What should I do?

thanks,
Alon

Answer (score 2):

You actually need two groups in your expression:

```
 Txt.replace(/([^ ])([.#:])/g, '$1 &$2').split(" ");
```