# How to create multiple variation array from a string using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I have this string:

```
foo = "moon is.white #small"
```

I want to convert it to this array using rules such as after "." and "#" split and add & if there is no white space before it. I got the answer in this thread: [How to Split string with multiple rules in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351907/how-to-split-string-with-multiple-rules-in-javascript#comment11806376_9351907) and this is what I got and it is great:

```
fooArr[0] = ['moon','is','&.white','#small']
```

**My Question is - How do I make other variations of the string to get multiple-variation Array with these rules**

A. split in different positions (sometimes the spaces will split and sometimes 2 words and more will be considers as one - in ALL variations (pay attention that if I don't split words with "." or "#" then I don't add "&".

```
fooArr[1] = ['moon is','&.white','#small']
fooArr[2] = ['moon is.white','#small']
foorArr[3] = ['moon','is.white','#small']
etc...
```

B. If there is "." or "#" then I want all variations of order between them -- `".all#is.good"` can be --> `[.all#is.good] & [.all.good#is] & [.good.all#is]` etc... (and I want it combined with variations from the first rule such as `[.all,&.good,&#is] & [.all.good,$#is]`) so I will have ALL COMBINATIONS OF BOTH A AND B

Eventually I need an array combining all the combinations of A and B (it should give me a lot of variations: `fooArr[0]..fooArr[X]`.

Where do I start?

Answer (score 0):

Use a series of regular expression to find all the places where you want to split the string and replace it with " &". Then split on " ".

Or, use a loop to move through the string create replacements like above. And then split.

Or, use a loop to move through the string and build the array directly.